# Unable to access google.com with FireFox Windows

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I can ping google.com and it's dns servers but I just can't seem to open google.com/ncr on Windows 10 PC **but** I'm able to access it with Chrome (same PC) and also OSX's Firefox (same build) (macbook on same network)

I was able to reproduce this issue on a windows laptop as well running the same build and windows 10(also same network)

I've uploaded the screen record here: https://gfycat.com/FrenchWellwornIaerismetalmark

Comment: is it working from this link: https://www.google.com/ncr ? I saw that it is trying to access google via http, what if you manually enter https?

Comment: @Divin3 No, it does not. If you try to access google.com/ncr it will automatically redirect to www, no? 
Edit: Entering the https:// shows nothing in the console except "Connected to google.com"

Comment: No, it can be a DNS problem. One more thing you should try is entering the ip address into the URL: http://216.58.199.132:80

Comment: @Divin3 https://gfycat.com/NegligibleRecentAmazonparrot

Comment: Can you access google with MS edge/internet explorer? Also, can you access other http**s** sites?

Comment: @Divin3 Similar issue on the Edge/IE but it's a hit or miss on .com but /ncr just doesn't open. http://imgur.com/a/bTYIu

Comment: This sounds pretty odd. I am starting to run out if ideas. A few more thing you should try: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813444 ignore steps: 1, 2, 6